# Does Mercy's damage boost apply to turrets?

Tags: overwatch

Torbjorn's turret is his main feature. It provides area denial and slows down offensive pushes. As a Mercy, if I damage boost Torbjorn, does his turret also see this benefit, or only his rivet gun? Same goes for Symmetra, are her sentries impacted by damage boost or not?